# Dynamics CRM 2013: How to set a custom role's Campaign Response (activity pointer) privileges

Tags: response, dynamics-crm-2013, privileges, user-roles

I have a custom role for which I want to set the privileges against the Campaign Response (activity pointer) entity.

From what I can see this is not possible, but I might be wrong.
I'm using CRM Dynamics 2013 On-Premise.

Thanks
Kobus

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Campaign Response is an activity entity, so its permission set is grouped with all other activity entities. Set the activity permissions to set the campaign response permissions.

[image]

Comment: Hi James

Thanks for the reply. My instance of CRM 2013 on-prem does not have "Activity" as a Core entity to set privileges against. 
Any thoughts about that?

Thanks

Comment: Aaah.. Sorted.. Turns out the Activity entity was renamed to Interactions. Thanks James